# How can drag and drop be achieved with Javascript and Wicket 6?

Tags: java, javascript, tree, drag-and-drop, wicket-6

I have an inventory application in written in Apache Wicket 6, in which I want to add a drag and drop feature in the organisation tree structure which shows the taxonomy of the organisation. So, with drag and drop, I want to achieve the ability to change the hierarchy of nodes, which is stored in the database.

[image]

I'm guessing I would require javascript, event handling in java, Java Persistence API to achieve this. But I have not been able to move even a step forward from there. How and what event do I trigger that the java side of the application will detect?

I am a newbie in java, so please show patience with my limited knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/), which is a plugin for jQuery.
I don't know Wicket, but I am sure this will help from javascript point of view.